# Read CSV from std::vector<unsigned char> using Apache Arrow

Tags: c++, csv, apache-arrow

I am trying to read a csv input format using Apache arrow. The example [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/csv.html) mentions that the input should be an [InputStream](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/io.html#_CPPv4N5arrow2io11InputStreamE), however in my case I just have an std::vector of unsigned chars. Is it possible to parse this using apache arrow? I have checked the [I/O interface](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/io.html) to see if there is an "in-memory" data structure with no luck.
I copy-paste the example code for convenience here as well as my input data:

```
#include "arrow/csv/api.h"

{
   // ...
   std::vector<unsigned char> data;
   arrow::io::IOContext io_context = arrow::io::default_io_context();
   // how can I fit the std::vector to the input stream? 
   std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::InputStream> input = ...;

   auto read_options = arrow::csv::ReadOptions::Defaults();
   auto parse_options = arrow::csv::ParseOptions::Defaults();
   auto convert_options = arrow::csv::ConvertOptions::Defaults();

   // Instantiate TableReader from input stream and options
   auto maybe_reader =
     arrow::csv::TableReader::Make(io_context,
                                   input,
                                   read_options,
                                   parse_options,
                                   convert_options);
   if (!maybe_reader.ok()) {
      // Handle TableReader instantiation error...
   }
   std::shared_ptr<arrow::csv::TableReader> reader = *maybe_reader;

   // Read table from CSV file
   auto maybe_table = reader->Read();
   if (!maybe_table.ok()) {
      // Handle CSV read error
      // (for example a CSV syntax error or failed type conversion)
   }
   std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = *maybe_table;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I/O interface docs list [BufferReader](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/io.html#_CPPv4N5arrow2io12BufferReaderE) which works as an in-memory input stream. While not listed in the docs, it [can be constructed from a pointer and a size](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/maint-4.0.x/cpp/src/arrow/io/memory.h#L148-L150) which should let you use your `vector<char>`.